# Checking for changes in Firebase database while application is closed

Tags: android, service, firebase

What is the 'right' way to set up checking for changes of a value in Firebase DB, while application is closed, and then push notifications to a user?

Should I use `Service`, `Alarm` and `pendingService` classes to get that done?

Comment: use Service as it will run in background and you can easily keep track on Firebase db and use FCM  for push notification to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use android Service to run your tasks on background even after your app has closed.

Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) on how to use the android services to run background tasks.

Also Alarm and pending services work best if your background task gets triggered upon change in other system parameters such as connectivity or any specific time interval or time.